# File save intent like share intent Android/iOS react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, android-intent

need to create a react-native application, in which user can record audio and save to any cloud services like google drive, dropbox, iCloud etc installed in his phone(not to share apps).

My question is whether any one has come across such react component, which shows all installed services only that support file upload. I googled but what I got is to access files from such services. Didn't get anything to create a file there. Got components to share files, but it open all the sharing apps. I want only those, which support upload and give me back the URL by which I can access it later.

Since I got nothing, I like to check if it can be achieve in native application. So I tried an android application with ACTION_CREATE_INTENT(this is the only one suit for my intention, right?). But it didn't show my dropbox installed, only the phone space and gdrive is listed. Please correct me, How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I used these two libraries :

https://github.com/Elyx0/react-native-document-picker

which allowed me to pick a document from my local device, ICloud (ios), box & drop box.  Then I used

https://github.com/joltup/react-native-fetch-blob

To upload Content and other features.  I don't know if this is what your looking for.